# How show different data based on the user gmail address in a Google apps script web application?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

Any ideas on how to show data from a spreadsheet in a google apps script web application based on the gmail address of the user?, how to set user permissions to see data in web application?

Thanks!

Comment: The good old `if then` isn't good enough for you any more? ;)

Comment: As it's currently written, this question is unclear. Can you provide more information about your situation and your desired goal? Do you have a code you're working on? What's the structure of the spreadsheet data?